# Getting thumbnail from a video url asynchronously - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, asynchronous, uiimageview

There are lot of example codes for getting thumbnail from a video url. But all of them I tried are NOT generating the image asynchronously. So, when it comes to multiple videos in a tableview, app freezes. Please help me to make this thumbnail asynchronously.

```
-(UIImage *)generateThumbnailIconForVideoFileWith:(NSURL *)contentURL WithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIImage *theImage = nil;
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:contentURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.maximumSize=size;
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(100,100); //change whatever you want here.
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
   theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef] ;
   CGImageRelease(imgRef);
   return theImage;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `MPMovieplayer`for generating thumbnail

```
   MPMoviePlayerController *player= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:Videourl];
   self.imgshow.image = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:5.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

  [player stop];
```

Comment: Will this request the entire video before generating the thumb?

Comment: yeah it will take lot for big video so create thumbnail one time and save it and use it after